# QGIS Authentication System for plugin manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, authentication

Does anyone have any details/documentation or information yet on the new Authentication System for Plugin Manager added to QGIS v2.14?

We would love some more information, and in particular if it resolves previously known issues with regard to the storage of login details on a secure network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only piece of documentation I found is the QEP (QGIS Enhancement Proposals) for the plugin:

- [QEP 14: Authentication configuration system with master password](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/35)

which includes a lot of information on how the plugin works and future proposals. However, as mentioned by Larry Shaffer (developer of the plugin) on 19th March 2016, in the [QGIS GitHub for documentation](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/645):

> ...the documentation associated with the original QEP is outdated and needs redone to fit the final implementation, and the added features not noted there. **I can have a revamped version of the authentication system docs in April, possibly starting a little earlier on it**.

---

I think the official documentation for QGIS 2.14 has already begun according to Alexandre Neto who was responding to Larry:

> **Larry**: *What is the release schedule for the 2.14 documentation?
>   I am swamped right now, but the documentation associated with the original QEP is outdated and needs redone to fit the final implementation, and the added features not noted there. I can have a revamped version of the authentication system docs in April, possibly starting a little earlier on it.*
>
> **Alexandre**: *I was planning to start document this next week. Do you think I can start the QEP and try to figure out what have changed myself? You would only have to review it and make smaller changes.*